# unpermitted attributes even after whitelisting in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

project details -> rails 5.1 and ruby 2.4.1

I'm trying to create a simple todo app. my problem is with nested model forms.
if i create a project without any task and i save it. then if i want to edit the project and add some tasks, tasks fields are not showing up. If i add tasks while creating the projects everything works as expected.in edit page i can see both project and tasks and i can edit as well.

below are my 2 models. I didnt use nested routes. just using the nested model forms.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :project, dependent: :destroy
   validates :name, presence: :true
   validates :description, presence: :true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :tasks
end
```

Below is my _form partial for new and edit.

```
<%= form_for @project do |form| %>
        <% if @project.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :name %>
        <%= form.text_field :name, id: :project_name %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :description %>
        <%= form.text_field :description, id: :project_description %>
      </div>

      <%= form.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= task_form.label :task_name %>
          <%= task_form.text_field :name, id: :task_name %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <%= task_form.label :task_description %>
          <%= task_form.text_field :description, id: :task_description %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= form.submit  %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

white listing of the project controller is given below.

```
 def project_params
   params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, tasks_attributes: [:id, :name, :description])
 end
```

Any help is appreciated
-Ajith

Comment: Your problem appears to be with whitelisting but you haven't included any controller code that would demonstrate how you're whitelisting `params`.

Comment: added the whitelisting. which action from projects controller is needed for more clarity. i will upload that as well.thnx

Comment: @Ajith From the looks of it, your code should work. So probably there is something else that gets sent. You can force an error and see which parameters were rejected by temporarily adding this in your *application.rb* (needs server restart): `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise`

Comment: @Ajith oh actually the following is what it is supposed to be, so there's no problem there: "if i create a project without any task and i save it. then if i want to edit the project and add some tasks, tasks fields are not showing up."

Comment: @Ajith ... you'll probably want something like my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i create a project without any task and i save it. then if i want to edit the project and add some tasks, tasks fields are not showing up.

... is how it is actually supposed to be. So your problem most likely is not related to Strong Parameters problem, as I do not see any obvious problems in your view file and your `project_params` method. Now since you don't want that this behaviour, you'll probably want something like the following which builds up 1 or more `task` objects by default if there's no `task` object associated to the`project` yet, so that there will always be at least one group of `task` fields when you're creating or editing a `project`.

**app/controllers/projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.tasks.build
    # the above code just above is the same as below
    # @project.tasks << Task.new

    # now you can call this again like below, if you want 2 groups of `tasks` fields when you're creating a Project
    @project.tasks.build
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    # this project may not yet have a `Task` object associated to it; if so we build a `Task` object like so
    # this builds 3 `Task` objects; you can just use one below if you just want to show one in your edit form.
    if @project.tasks.count == 0
      @project.tasks.build
      @project.tasks.build
      @project.tasks.build
    end
  end
end
```

*P.S. you may be interested in [`cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem if you want to have a form that can build dynamic nested attributes automatically for you (like for example you want 2 buttons like the following) '(Add more task)' and '(Remove this task)`*

Comment: This seems fine for me. but as a better option i will add buttons to add and remove tasks. Thanks

Comment: @Ajith No prob! Yes `cocoon` is good. Feel free to try it out! :)